# How to do scheduling on OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, scheduler

I knew that [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) have a runtime scheduler.

But I couldn’t find how to do scheduling on OpenCL.

Does anyone know about the OpenCL scheduler?

Comment: Could you be more specific? You have no control over thread or block scheduling in OpenCL.

Comment: I wonder about task allocation from host, The host transfers some tasks to command queue and the tasks in the command queue are allocated just sequentially?

Comment: If the command queue was created with the out-of-order flag, then the implementation may execute operations as it sees fit (while still honoring dependencies between tasks, if any). Otherwise the commands are executed in order.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so do you think designing OpenCL scheduler is a good subject of research?

Comment: Yes, designing a good scheduler is still an open problem (and a hard one), notably when scheduling across devices of different performance characteristics.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can solve my curiosity because of you. Have a nice day